# Break if statement for a dispatch function - TypeScript, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

A little bit of context .
I have a `dispatch` function that triggers my `GET axios` call to fetch the status of a progress bar .
So far it is working fine , but the problem is that the function continues even if the status is `finished` . Can someone give me a suggestion what can i do ? Here is a part of the code that i use

```
  const [responseId] = useState(response.data.id)

  const [processed, setProcessed] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('');


        if (responseId) {
          dispatch(fetchStatus(responseId));
        if (status === 'finished') {
          console.log('finished');
          return;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (statusProgress) {
      setProcessed(statusProgress.processed);
      setTotal(statusProgress.total);
      setStatus(statusProgress.status);
    }
  }, [statusProgress]);
```

I gave it a try with nested `IF` or `IF ELSE` , but the effect is the same .

Comment: What is the function? Did you just cut the if part from the function? The indentation and curly brackets are really confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue to fetch data until `status !== 'finished'`. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (responseId && status !== 'finished') {
     dispatch(fetchStatus(responseId));
  }
  else if(status === 'finished') {
     console.log('finished');
  }
}, [responseId, status]);
```

This `useEffect` will be executed every time `status` and/or `responseId` change values.

I used a `useEffect` because I always avoid to write code directly in component's body (because is impossible to know how many times and when the code will be executed).

Comment: It seems that it will work , but it makes only 3 calls in total then it stops . It is not going into the `ELSE IF` statement

Comment: @PandaMastr most probably because you are not setting `status`...

Comment: The server has stopped . It is working like this . If i want to enchance the argument can i do something like  `if (fileSelected && status !== 'finished' && processed !== total )` and then `else if (status === 'finished'  && processed == total)`